# Codeigniter specific URL rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

In one of my CI application I got a controller called movies in which I am showing details of a movie, its URL looks like

```
http://localhost/movies/index/12/Movie-Name
```

here 12 is the movie id which is used for fetching values from db and movie name, which is using for SEO URL.

I would likes to rewrite this URL to

```
http://localhost/12-Movie-Name
```

I already removed index.php from my application using http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want the user to access `/movies/index/12/Movie-Name` or `/12-Movie-Name`?

Comment: user access /12-Movie-Name and show the details of movie with primary key 12.. thanks for the reply .. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try

```
RewriteRule    ^/([0-9]+)\-([^/]+?)/?$  /movies/index/$1/$2
```

Although it may cause problems with other parts of your Codeigniter application.

Comment: any solution to avoid problems in other parts ?

Comment: I'm not sure, it depends on how you route your application.  You should probably check it out, though, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

or you can add this to Codeigniter router

```
$router['/(:any)'] = 'movies/index/12/$1';
```

but your movies id need to set as string with title.